# trying to create Say/Do ratio grid, facing issues with getting data in particular format

Tags: extjs, rally, extjs4.2

ACtually I am creating a Say/Do ratio Grid, which is now looking something like this.

[image]

wanted to show points accepted, commited and the ratio using IterationCumulativeFlowData for each Iteration. For that I want this data in following format one Array of Iteration Ids, and for each Iteration ID the array of 70 IterationCumulativeFlowData, but I am not getting this correctly
I also posting some my code, please need ur suggestions where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance

```
Object->
   12788831428: Array[70]
   12788831496: Array[70]
   12788831702: Array[70]
   12788831704: Array[70]
   12788831706: Array[70]

            getCommulativeData: function(iteration) {   
                var secFilter = [];
                parsecumulativeflowdata = {};
                //console.log("itetetetete value", iteration[0].ObjectID);  
                for( i = 1; i < iteration.length - 1; i++){
                    if (i == 1) {
                        var filter1 = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
                            property: 'IterationObjectID',
                            operator: '=',
                            value: iteration[i].ObjectID
                        });
                        filter1 = filter1.or({
                            property: 'IterationObjectID',
                            operator: '=',
                            value: iteration[i+1].ObjectID
                        }); 
                    }   
                    else {
                        filter1 = filter1.or({
                            property: 'IterationObjectID',
                            operator: '=',
                            value: iteration[i].ObjectID
                        });                         
                    }   
                };
                secFilter.push(filter1);
                console.log("filter value", secFilter);
                var filter = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
                    property: 'IterationObjectID',
                    operator: '=',
                    value: iteration[0].ObjectID
                });
                filter = filter.or(secFilter);          
                filter.toString();
                //var val = iteration[i].ObjectID;
                Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    //limit: Infinity,
                    model: 'IterationCumulativeFlowData',
                    context: {
                        project: this.getContext().getProject()._ref,
                        projectScopeDown: true,
                        projectScopeUp: false
                    },                          
                    fetch: ['CreationDate','CardEstimateTotal','CardState', 'IterationObjectID', 'Project'],
                    filters: [
                        secFilter
                    ],  
                    listeners: {
                        load: function(store, records) {
                            var iterationArray = {};
                            var cumulativeflowArray = [];
                            console.log("cummulative flow", records);
                            Ext.Array.each(records, function(record){
                                cumulativeflowArray.push(record.data);
                                iterationArray[record.data.IterationObjectID] = Ext.Array.flatten(cumulativeflowArray);
                            }, this);
                            console.log("iterationarray values", iterationArray);
                            //this.recurseCommulativeArray[record.IterationObjectID] = Ext.Array.flatten(cumulativeflowArray);
                        },
                        scope: this
                    }
                    //return 
                }, this);
```

getCommulativeData: function(iteration) - in this iteration is the array of 12 objects for 3 teams and four sprints(26.1, 26.2, 26.3, 26.4), so it has 12 objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was not looping it correctly, it should be like this.

`getCommulativeData: function(iteration) {

                    console.log("itetetetete value", iteration);

                    var secFilter = [];
                    var filter1 = null;
                    parsecumulativeflowdata = {};
                    for( i = 0; i < iteration.length; i++){
                        if (i == 0) {
                            filter1 = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
                                property: 'IterationObjectID',
                                operator: '=',
                                value: iteration[i].ObjectID
                            });
                        }

                        else {
                            filter1 = filter1.or({
                                property: 'IterationObjectID',
                                operator: '=',
                                value: iteration[i].ObjectID
                            });

                        }

                        //secFilter.push(filter1);
                    };`